# how to equalize all ios audio streams?

Tags: ios, audio

I decided to write an equalizer of ios, which would allow to change the level of audio frequencies to improve the audibility of sound for people with hearing problems. For example in my left ear is missing audibility of high frequencies, and I would like to be able to increase the high frequencies in all applications (skype, youtube etc), including a voice call over the cellular connection. How it could be implemented? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is code? And by the way the question you asked has many opinion based answers. So, i would say. please be more specific and ask the question again along with the code you try.

Comment: Specifically, I want to be able to adjust audio frequency levels (low, medium, high), for example for mac os I use http://www.bitgapp.com/eqmac/ but the source is unavailable, this equalizer is very helpful to increase the audibility of sound in all applications that use audio and I want to do likewise for ios